# (C) parsing std in into a linked list, infinite loop

Tags: c, scanf

For some reason the code keeps segfaulting after the first printf at the for loop near the end. It doesnt print the 2nd printf at all, can someone point me in the right direction? I think it has to do with a problem in memory

```
struct node{
    char *fullString;
    char fileName[1024];
    int  lineNumber;
    char filler[1024];
    struct node *next;
}; 

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{

    char tmpstring[1024];
    /* This won't change, or we would lose the list in memory */
    struct node *head = NULL;       
    //tail
    struct node *tail = NULL;  
    /* This will point to each node as it traverses the list */
    struct node *ptr, *newnode;  

    while (fgets(tmpstring, 1024, stdin) == tmpstring) 
    {
      if ((newnode = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node))) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr,"mklist: malloc failure for newnode\n");
        exit(1);
        }
        if ((newnode->fullString = malloc(strlen(tmpstring)+1)) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr,"mklist: malloc failure for newnode->str\n");
        exit(1);
        }
        if (strncpy(newnode->fullString, tmpstring, strlen(tmpstring)+1) != newnode->fullString) {
        fprintf(stderr,"mklist: string copy problem\n");
        exit(1);
        }

      strcpy(newnode->fullString, tmpstring);
      newnode->next = NULL;

//      if (3 != scanf(tmpstring, "%255s:%d:%255s", newnode->fileName, &newnode->lineNumber, newnode->filler))
 //       abort();

      if (tail == NULL)
        head = tail = newnode;
      else {
        tail->next = newnode;
        tail = newnode;
      }
    }

    // Now print the list, element by element.
    for (ptr = head; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr->next)
        printf("%s\n", ptr->fullString);
        printf("%s:%d:%s\n", ptr->fileName, ptr->lineNumber, ptr->filler);
}
```

Comment: [strcmp](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp)

Comment: how does this help me?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Your `fgets` loop doesn't allocate any memory, so you are just filling your list with garbage unallocated pointers (`newnode` isn't set until after the loop).

Comment: I suspect you can remove most of this code -- all the node and pointer stuff -- and still get the same error.

Comment: @nneonneo Im trying to parse a stdin into 3 attributes of a node in a linked list. 1 node per line of stdin

newnode is set in the loop!

Comment: @Beta The thing is Im new to c programming and I dont know what is crucial to it, this code is mostly sample code from the web

Comment: When your code doesn't work, it's a good idea to whittle it down to the [simplest complete example that reproduces the error](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Before that you should do the same thing in reverse: when writing new code, start with something small and simple, get it working perfectly, then add complexity a little at a time and *never add to code that doesn't work.* These are good practices in general, not specific to C. In this case I think you guessed correctly: you're using `fgets` the wrong way.

Comment: Your input loop condition looks proper to me.  Are you sure you feed it input that ends with an EOF?  If you run this without feeding it a file, then it will hang trying to read input from the terminal until someone inputs an EOF (typically ctrl-D).

Comment: Im feeding it the output of the grep function in the command line, the purpose of this is not to read from a file, where does it try to read an EOF?

Comment: That will work fine.  grep will put an EOF at the end of its output.  If you tried to manually input data by typing it in, then you would need to end your input with an EOF (ctrl-D typically) to end your input loop.

Comment: I have found out the source of the error is the scanf, everything else works if I take that out, am I using it incorrectly?

Comment: No, your code is pretty badly broken as is, even without the extra scanf's.  Take a look at my answer below which is doing what I think you were after.  Your main problem is that you never allocate any node's for newnode / your list and even if you did, your node type itself doesn't contain any memory for the members you want to store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define MAX_LINE_SIZE 1024

struct node
{
  char fullString[MAX_LINE_SIZE];
  char fileName[MAX_LINE_SIZE];
  int  lineNumber;
  char filler[MAX_LINE_SIZE];

  struct node *next;
};  

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  char tmpstring[MAX_LINE_SIZE];
  struct node *head = NULL;
  struct node *tail = NULL;
  struct node *ptr, *newnode;  

  while (fgets(tmpstring, MAX_LINE_SIZE, stdin)) 
  {
    size_t len = strlen(tmpstring);
    char *cptr = tmpstring, *eptr;

    if (0 == len || tmpstring[len - 1] != '\n')
      assert(0), abort();  /* NOTE: will abort on too long lines and if EOF occurs mid-line */

    if (NULL == (newnode = calloc(1, sizeof(struct node))))
      assert(0), abort();

    strcpy(newnode->fullString, tmpstring);
    newnode->lineNumber = -1;
    newnode->next = NULL;

    if (NULL == (eptr = strchr(cptr, ':')))
      assert(0), abort();

    *eptr = '\0';
    if (1 != sscanf(cptr, "%255s", newnode->fileName))
      assert(0), abort();

    cptr = eptr + 1;

    if (NULL == (eptr = strchr(cptr, ':')))
      assert(0), abort();

    *eptr = '\0';
    if (1 != sscanf(cptr, "%d", &newnode->lineNumber))
      assert(0), abort();

    cptr = eptr + 1;
    strcpy(newnode->filler, cptr);

    if (tail == NULL)
      head = tail = newnode;
    else {
      tail->next = newnode;
      tail = newnode;
    }
  }

  for (ptr = head; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr->next)
    printf("%s:%d:%s", ptr->fileName, ptr->lineNumber, ptr->filler);    

  return 0;
}
```

Add some better error handling and that's probably what you were after -- so long as your input doesn't have lines longer than MAX_LINE_SIZE-1 characters.

Comment: when I replaced the code with this it still aborts, same problem

Comment: If it's aborting on the call to sscanf, then ensure that your input comports to the line format: <str>:<num>:<str>\n.  If it doesn't, then the abort() will be called.  In particular, you might want to crank the size of tmpstring up to 256 and alter the fgets similarly too.  Even better, you can check that the last non-nul character of tmpstring is '\n' after you read it in.  If it isn't, then the line was longer than 256 characters and your input loop / parsing won't work as expected.

Comment: Yeah the sscanf is wrong.  If there aren't any spaces, then the first %s will grab as many characters as possible, including ':', which isn't what you want.  I'll edit my code to work better.

Comment: youre right, for some reason when I try to just print in the for loop, it seg faults after returnig what grep would return(the first printf), without printing the 2nd printf. How can I fix it? I have updated the code

Comment: Something like the new code I edited.  Alternatively you could use the strtok() function to accomplish something similar.

Comment: Unfortunately when I put this code in it still seg faults, does it run on your  terminal?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71139/discussion-between-fullcombatbeard-and-jschultz410).

Comment: I compiled and tested the code and it seemed to work.